# Thousands of socket connections without creating separate threads for each one

Tags: kotlin, websocket, kotlin-coroutines, okhttp

I have 1000 users. I want to create a separate websocket connection for each of them, but NOT allocate a separate thread for each user. I would like to ensure that the okHttp3 client uses coroutines, rather than creating a separate thread for each call to `client.newWebSocket(request, listener)`

Is the okHttp3 client suitable for this solution and how can I achieve this?

Updated:

I tried to use the ktor http client on coroutines, which creates a custom pool of 4 threads.
But I see that it still creates hundreds of DefaultDispatcher-worker-*number* threads.
How do I override the maximum possible number of DefaultDispatcher-worker? I want coroutines and a pool of 4 threads to be used for 4358 websocket connections.

```
suspend fun main() {
    val dispatcher = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4).asCoroutineDispatcher()

    val jobs = mutableListOf<Job>()

    val credentials = readCsvFile("/creds_4358.csv")
    val client =
        HttpClient(CIO) {
            engine {
                maxConnectionsCount = 10000
                endpoint {
                    maxConnectionsPerRoute = 1000000
                    pipelineMaxSize = 20
                    keepAliveTime = 5000
                    connectTimeout = 5000
                    connectAttempts = 5
                }
            }
            install(WebSockets) {
                pingInterval = 2000
            }
        }
    credentials.forEach { cred ->
        val job =
            GlobalScope.launch(dispatcher) {
                client.webSocket(
                    method = HttpMethod.Get,
                    host = "stream-testnet.bybit.com",
                    port = 80,
                    path = "/v5/private?max_alive_time=10m",
                ) {
                    auth(cred)
                    subscribe()
                    println("I'm working in thread ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
                    for (message in incoming) {
                        if (message is Frame.Text) {
                            val text = message.readText()
                            println("Received message from server: $text")
                        }
                    }
                    close()
                }
            }
        jobs.add(job)
    }
    jobs.joinAll()
    client.close()
    println("Connection closed. Goodbye!")
}
```

Comment: Why would the client have that many websocket connections? Isn't it 1 user per client? The client would just have a single websocket connection or not?

Comment: We have 1000 clients, they have their own credentials. And each client connects to the server’s websocket connection to listen to incoming messages.

Comment: no, all users are connected through 1 instance of the okhttpclient

Comment: Yes, 1 client - 1 connection

Answer (score 0):

OkHttp uses one thread per web socket. You can use JDK 21 virtual threads if you’d like to scale the web socket count without much cost.

Comment: Yes, I use Kotlin Couroutines using a ktor http client that creates both a custom pool of 4 threads and hundreds of DefaultDispatcher-worker-*number*. How do I override the maximum possible number of DefaultDispatcher-worker? (update question)